# iPhone:Popup window with storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uistoryboard

I would like to make a popupwindow like this:

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/showing-a-popup-window-in-ios-class-for-download/

However, It doesn't work on my xcode because i am developing an app for ios5, using a storyboard.
Do you know any othere examples similar to this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you cannot create the view you need using a Nib file and then add that view pro grammatically with a VC controlled by storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Storyboards handle the kind of window you are talking about.

Make your segue "Modal", "Form Sheet", and "Default"

Then your new window make the size "Form Sheet".

This should get you something similar to what you want without resorting to NIBs.